# Can we say "Only 70000 of Muhammeds(pbuh) followers will enter Paradise"?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, jannah, day-of-judgement, jahannam

There are many hadiths which says only 70000 of last Prophets followers will enter paradise without reckoning
e.g

> **Sahih Bukhari Volume 008, Book 076, Hadith Number 549.**  Narated By Ibn
>   'Abbas : The Prophet said, "The people were displayed in front of me
>   and I saw one prophet passing by with a large group of his followers,
>   and another prophet passing by with only a small group of people, and
>   another prophet passing by with only ten (persons), and another
>   prophet passing by with only five (persons), and another prophet
>   passed by alone. And then I looked and saw a large multitude of
>   people, so I asked Gabriel, "Are these people my followers?' He said,
>   'No, but look towards the horizon.' I looked and saw a very large
>   multitude of people. Gabriel said. 'Those are your followers, and
>   those are seventy thousand (persons) in front of them who will neither
>   have any reckoning of their accounts nor will receive any punishment.'
>   I asked, 'Why?' He said, 'For they used not to treat themselves with
>   branding (cauterization) nor with Ruqya (get oneself treated by the
>   recitation of some Verses of the Qur'an) and not to see evil omen in
>   things, and they used to put their trust (only) in their Lord." On
>   hearing that, 'Ukasha bin Mihsan got up and said (to the Prophet),
>   "Invoke Allah to make me one of them." The Prophet said, "O Allah,
>   make him one of them." Then another man got up and said (to the
>   Prophet), "Invoke Allah to make me one of them." The Prophet said,
>   'Ukasha has preceded you."
>
> **Sahih Bukhari Volume 008, Book 076, Hadith Number 479**.  Narated By Ibn
>   Abbas : Allah's Apostle said, "Seventy thousand people of my followers
>   will enter Paradise without accounts, and they are those who do not
>   practice Ar-Ruqya and do not see an evil omen in things, and put their
>   trust in their Lord.

and there are many more similar hadiths which have the same meaning "70000 without reckoning"

someone can say this hadith talks only about people entering paradise **without reckoning** . But this is not the correct view if you read some other hadiths.

> **Sahih Bukhari Volume 008, Book 076, Hadith Number 543**.  Narated By Ibn
>   Abi Mulaika : 'Aisha said, "The Prophet said, '**Anybody whose account
>   (record) is questioned will surely be punished.**' I said, 'Doesn't
>   Allah say: 'He surely will receive an easy reckoning?' (84.8) The
>   Prophet replied. 'This means only the presentation of the account.'"
>
> **Sahih Bukhari Volume 008, Book 076, Hadith Number 545**.  Narated By
>   'Aisha : Allah's Apostle, said, "**None will be called to account on the
>   Day of Resurrection, but will be ruined.**" I said "O Allah's Apostle!
>   Hasn't Allah said: 'Then as for him who will be given his record in
>   his right hand, he surely will receive an easy reckoning? (84.7-8)...
>   Allah's Apostle said, "That (Verse) means only the presentation of the
>   accounts, but anybody whose account (record) is questioned on the Day
>   of Resurrection, will surely be punished."

Question

Can we say "Only 70000 of Muhammeds(pbuh) followers will enter Paradise" ?

Answer (score 3):

The Hadith you mentioned talks about the 70000 who will enter paradise **without being brought into account**. And they are the best people from this ummah.

However, the total number of people going to paradise from this ummah is known only to Allah (SWT). The reason why those 70000 will not be the only one is because:

> There is good news for all of us Muslims in this hadeeth and others.
> There is more information in a report narrated in the Musnad of Imaam
> Ahmad and the Sunan of al-Tirmidhi and Ibn Maajah, where Abu Umaamah
> is reported to have said that the Prophet (peace and blessings of
> Allaah be upon him) said: “My Lord promised me that seventy thousand
> of my ummah will enter Paradise without being brought to account or
> being punished; with each thousand of them will be another seventy
> thousand, plus three handfuls of the handfuls of my Lord, may He be
> glorified.” We ask Allaah to make us among them. Just imagine: seventy
> thousand, with each thousand of whom is another seventy thousand – how
> great will be the total number of people who will enter Paradise
> without being brought to account? How many will be in each handful
> “scooped up” by the Merciful, Compassionate, Generous Almighty Lord?
> We ask Allaah to make us among that number.
>
> **Source**: [islamqa](http://islamqa.info/en/4203)

Answer (score 1):

> There are many hadiths which says only 70000 of last Prophets followers will enter paradise **without reckoning**
>
> Can we say "**Only** 70000 of Muhammeds(pbuh) followers will enter Paradise"?

No. The 1st Hadith clearly says "neither have any reckoning of their accounts nor will receive any punishment" but it doesn't say only these many people will enter paradise and the rest will burn in hell. It is they won't have any calculations of their deeds whether they did good or bad, they just straight away enter Paradise. But for others, calculations happen, and if found guilty of some bad deed, they will be paid thereof by letting them burn in hell for sometime until the creator wishes. Apart from that, every believer in **One God** who does **righteous good deeds** will enter paradise **for sure** (Insha Allah).

May the creator guide us all.